# @generated value - get value of ID

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

ID is auto generated when persisting the object of vehicle into database. How can I get value of ID, without persisting it?

Here is code:

```
public class Vehicle{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    int id;
    private int year;
    private String model;
    //getters, setters
}
```

UPDATE

```
    public void updateVehicle(Vehicle vehicle) {

        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Vehicle vehicleDB = em.find(Vehicle.class, vehicle.getId());
        vehicleDB.setYear(vehicle.getYear());
        vehicleDB.setModel(vehicle.getModel());
        em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, as it is generated by the database at the moment of persistence. Before that, the id is not defined.

Comment: Do you have some source for this statement?

Comment: Logic, you can not predict the ID of the object, as the database is responsible for managing the IDs of auto-incrementing columns. Your application can not say, which ID the database will generate next. Maybe the databases strategy is to add 2 to the new ID every time..instead of simple incrementation by 1.

Comment: I need value of generated ID for setting id for object of Vehicle

Comment: you don't set the ID, your persistence manager is doing this.

Comment: Yes I know. I need ID for object. So that can later search in Database by ID of the object.

Comment: your persistence manager inserts the ID automatically after persisting.. So after you persist the object, you could get the ID out of it by obj.getId()

Comment: What if I don't persisting. If I just searching and updating the object?

Comment: I think I don't understand your intention. If the object is not managed/persistent, then it doesn't have an ID. If it already is persistent, it already has an ID.

Comment: I've updated the code for understanding my intention. I have simple function for update Vehicle. I' don't know if vehicle.getId() will get any value?

Comment: If you want to update an existing record, you need know the ID of the entity. If the record is new, you don't set the id yourself. Normally, you know the ID of the existing entity, because you previously loaded it from the database.

Comment: In that case I will get value of vehicle.getId()?

Comment: yes, id will be set in the object, if it has been loaded before by the entity manager.

Answer (score -1):

We can't get it before save, but the simple solution is before save your object you can get it by select query.

Comment: This kind of solution can goes into race conditions. Don't do that!

Comment: Assumed solution is not correct, the sequence may be different from incrementing 1, furthermore there could happen an insert after this select and before the insert, so the ID is wrong.